# Why can't my laptop connect to internet while PC can?

Tags: networking

I am trying to connect my laptop to my modem but it keeps being unable to connect. I used the same UTP cable I am using right now for my computer aswell as Wi-Fi. Both don't work on my laptop but for some reason my UTP works on my PC. I tried searching what might be causing this and I thought I read something about DNS. I tried changing DNS to the one of Google or something (which would be `8.8.8.8` I think. This did not work. I also tried resetting the modem, without result here either. Anyone has any suggestions how I could fix this problem?

Comment: Is it a modem or a router? If it's really a modem, it may now be locked to your PC.

Comment: @DanielB It's a Cisco EPC 3925. What do you mean with being locked to my pc? How do I unlock it then (or get stuff to work again)?

Comment: That means it would only work with traffic from a known MAC adress, ie. your PC’s. Not very likely since it has WiFi, but who knows what silly restrictions your ISP put in place.

Answer (score 2):

#### Any suggestions how I could fix this problem?

Try re-initialising the various network states.

Open a `cmd` shell and do the following:

1. Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

   ```
   netsh winsock reset catalog
   ```
2. Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

   ```
   netsh int ip reset reset.log
   ```
3. Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall reset
   ```
4. Flush DNS resolver cache:

   ```
   ipconfig /flushdns
   ```
5. Flush routing table (reboot required)

   ```
   route /f
   ```

Comment: "netsh advfirewall reset" learned something new.

Comment: I tried to run all of these commands and no result...

Comment: If it's a cable modem it is probably locked to the MAC address of your PC. What is the make/model of your modem?

Comment: The model is a Cisco EPC 3925

Comment: @Barrosy Speak to your ISP. It should work with multiple devices connected via Ethernet.

Comment: @DavidPostill All right will do then. The weird thing also is when I hold the reset button, it won't turn off the lights or something likewise to put it back to factory settings (like I read about this modem on some other websites).